# Already Registered at /appname/: The model User is already registered

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm trying to connect the django.contrib.auth User with my own UserProfile, and I'm getting an 'AlreadyRegistered' error when I go on the site.

Here's the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: myurl.com/django/appname/

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.6.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'polls',
 'appname',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.humanize')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/var/www/mysite/mysite/urls.py" in <module>
  3. admin.autodiscover()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  29.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/var/www/mysite/appname/admin.py" in <module>
  4. admin.site.register(User)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in register
  80.                 raise AlreadyRegistered('The model %s is already registered' % model.__name__)

Exception Type: AlreadyRegistered at /appname/
Exception Value: The model User is already registered
```

I'm pretty sure this stems from my app's models.py, seeing as that's all I changed in a major way, I believe.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Tag(models.Model):
        pics = models.ManyToManyField('Picture', blank=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class UserProfile(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined')
        auth_user = models.OneToOneField(User)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
                UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

class Picture(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
        owner = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
        content = models.ImageField(upload_to='instaton')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Comment(models.Model):
        content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        date = models.DateTimeField('date commented')
        commenter = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
        pic = models.ForeignKey('Picture')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.content
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

When you define a custom user admin in your app's `admin.py`, you must first unregister the default `User` model admin before registering your own.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: This also happened when I modified my app to use the original auth.User object instead of my custom, poorly named User object. Thus my issue was trying to register the auth.User object when it's already registered. Removing the register(User) call fixed that.